# react useContext is reseting a web socket connection each time a page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, next.js, socket.io

I am using websocket for various parts of my nextJS app and need to export them everywhere while not resetting the socket connection. If it resets it drops all the rooms it was following which causes issues in my application. I use a context to make them global and initialize them inside my _app.tsx

this is my socket contexts in /contexts/socket.tsx

```
import socketio from "socket.io-client";
import React from "react";

export const socket = socketio();
export const SocketContext = React.createContext(socket);
```

here is the page that has issues at pages/chat/index.tsx

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import AppLayout from "../../layouts/AppLayout";
import useUser from '../../hooks/useUser';
import { SocketContext } from '../../contexts/socket';

export default function Chat() {
  const username = useUser().username;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<Message>>([]);

  const socket = useContext(SocketContext); //THIS resets if the page reloads despite being a context

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("newIncomingMessage", (msg: any) => {
      setMessages((currentMsg) => [
        ...currentMsg,
        { author: msg.author, message: msg.message },
      ]);
    });
  }, [])
}
```

this is how I initialize the socket in pages/_app.tsx

```
import { SocketContext, socket } from '../contexts/socket';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            <main>
                <Component {...pageProps} key={router.asPath} />
                <Toaster position="bottom-center" toastOptions={{ duration: 3000, }} />
            </main>
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default wrapper.withRedux(App);
```

I am using this for the backend for now pages/api/socket.tsx

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function SocketHandler(req: any, res: any) {
  // if socket server already initialized do nothing
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("server socket already set up");
    res.end();
  } else {
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    const onConnection = (socket: any) => {
      console.log('server new socket.id: ', socket.id)
      messageHandler(io, socket);
    };

    // Define actions inside
    io.on("connection", onConnection);
  }
  res.end();
}

//export messageHandler (io, socket) => { //if you take to another fule
function messageHandler(io: any, socket: any) {
  const createdMessage = (msg: any) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("newIncomingMessage", msg);
  };

  socket.on("createdMessage", createdMessage);
};
```

Comment: When you say *"THIS resets if the page reloads despite being a context"*, are you talking about a real refresh like with the browser refresh button?

Comment: It does it with the browser refresh button and if I navigate to a url manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move the socket creation to a higher level - simular to the way you would use Authentication or a Connection SQL Server. ~ like a singleton.